# How to find & delete files which have been deleted from disk but whose file handle hasn't been closed in Debian?

Tags: debian

I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE and would like to run automatic search-and-deletions to fully delete all files "which have been deleted but whose file handle hasn't been closed".

I'm still new to GNU/Linux and I've read that such files are a security risk (i.e. malware using this to hide its presence).

Apparently the `ls` command shows such files with a "reference count of 0" which is not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood something.

> fully delete all files which have been deleted

Well ... if a file is deleted, it is deleted.

If you want that deleting files invalidates all handles, that won't be possible. Too many programs and millions lines of codes rely on this semantics. As for the possibility to prevent deleting opened files, as Windows does, it's the same: Too many things in the Linux world rely on this.

Manually force-closing file handles in a foreign process, eg. with GDB or scriped solutions with it, will crash the process or do worse things. Invalidating the handle on kernel side has the same problems (and requires kernel modifications).

In short, there's no sane way to do this.

And, I wouldn't call it a security risk. If malware uses this to hide something, malware already is on your computer and can create and delete files. Then you have much more problems than this.